# Hide a select option

Tags: javascript

i have this function

```
    function showOptions(s)
    {
    var Variable = '<?php echo $d['role']; ?>';
    if (Variable =="Supervisor") {
    console.log(s[s.selectedIndex].value).hide(); 
    }
    else{
    console.log(s[s.selectedIndex].value).show();
    } 
    }
```

in have this select

```
  <select name="claimStatus1">
  <option>Make a selection</option> 
  <option style="display:none" value="changeEdit.php?id=<?php echo 
  $d['id'];?>#texte">Complete</option>  
 </select>
```

I would like to display the hidden option when variable in the function equal to Supervisor. I'm stuck to do it due to the link in the value, i don't know how to call it in the function, or it can be done other way.
Some help please !

Comment: Options can't be reliably hidden, some browsers allow it, some don't. The only way to "hide" an option, is to remove it.

Comment: What do you think `console.log(s[s.selectedIndex].value).hide();` does?